# Migration from session to authResponse: validating the sig on external server

Tags: facebook, session

We have (currently) working projects that use Javascript API to get the Facebook session object, pass it to a Flash client, and that Flash client then sends it to our Java socket server which validates the session without a call to Facebook itself, by concatenating the half dozen or so parts of the session object (not the sig) in a certain order, concatenating the app secret key at the end, then hashing.  This is compared to the sig, and it matches nicely for us, using the old api and a valid client.

On Oct 1st, the old api with session won't work any more. The authResponse object doesn't have the same fields.  It has accessToken, userID, expiresIn, and signedRequest.

Is there a way for our Java socket server to do a similar validation of an authResponse object, so that it doesn't have to make a Facebook call when the client logs in to the socket server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

javascript SDK sets a cookie on the client computer with the name fbsr_APP_ID
which is basically a "signed request", you can read what is signed request and how to validate and   decode it server-side here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I'm having difficulty getting it to work without using PHP however.  We are already juggling three languages on this project, and don't want to involve PHP as well.  I wish that the JS api had actual code docs.

Comment: Hi Teresa. Here you can find examples how to parse signed request in different languages: https://github.com/ptarjan/signed-request

Comment: Thanks Anatoly!  I'll check it out!

Comment: @Teresa. If you think I answered your question - pls accept/mark as answered, if you need more info/details, please comment then. thanks

Comment: I was waiting until I verified that it worked - and I just got that done.  Thank you SO much!